# Split database backup file using PowerShell and merge it back

Tags: windows, powershell, ssms

I am new to PowerShell having some issues with getting corrupted files when splitting and re attaching files back together using PowerShell.

I have a remote server from which I need to download a .bak file with the size of 44GB. To be able to do this I am splitting the files in to smaller (100mb) pieces using this script.

```
$from = "D:\largebakfile\largefile.bak"
$rootName = "D:\foldertoplacelargebakfile\part"
$ext = "PART_"
$upperBound = 100MB


$fromFile = [io.file]::OpenRead($from)
$buff = new-object byte[] $upperBound
$count = $idx = 0
try {
    do {
        "Reading $upperBound"
        $count = $fromFile.Read($buff, 0, $buff.Length)
        if ($count -gt 0) {
            $to = "{0}{1}{2}" -f ($rootName, $idx, $ext)
            $toFile = [io.file]::OpenWrite($to)
            try {
                "Writing $count to $to"
                $tofile.Write($buff, 0, $count)
            } finally {
                $tofile.Close()
            }
        }
        $idx ++
    } while ($count -gt 0)
}
finally {
    $fromFile.Close()
}
```

After this is done and the "PART_" files are downloaded to local computer I use this script to merge the files back together to 1 .bak file.

```
# replace with the location of the "PARTS" file
Set-Location "C:\Folderwithsplitfiles\Parts"

# replace with the SQL backup folder in your computer.
$outFile = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\newname.bak"

#The prefix for all PARTS files
$infilePrefix ="C:\Folderwithsplitfiles\Parts\PART_"


$ostream = [System.Io.File]::OpenWrite($outFile)
$chunkNum = 1
$infileName = "$infilePrefix$chunkNum"
$offset = 0
while(Test-Path $infileName) {
        $bytes = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($infileName)
        $ostream.Write($bytes, 0, $bytes.Count)
        Write-Host "read $infileName"
        $chunkNum += 1
        $infileName = "$infilePrefix$chunkNum"
}
$ostream.close();

#Get-FileHash $outfile | Format-List
```

When trying to restore database in SSMS I get an error basically saying that the file is corrupted and can't be restored.

I have been struggling with this a couple of days now and don't seem to get my head correct.

Everything seems like its working but something is causing me these errors. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Might I suggest you look at [Background Intelligent Transfer Service](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd819420.aspx), you should be able to download the whole file in one piece to save over complicating anything. (Also supports starting/stopping the transfer etc.)

Comment: Intresting!! Will check this out =)